# how to queue users who want to access the same database

Tags: php, mysql, queue

I am developing a web application which requires that multiple users submit there queries (each user on an average has at least 200 quires) and the queries are process through different statements in db. the system can process 8 queries/sec. 
when more then one user is accessing the application the db is getting more queries then it can handle. how can i queue the queries coming from different user so that all the users time delay is equal.

All your suggessions are most appritiated

I am using php and mysql

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a Vic20 as a server? How can your system only process 8 requests per second??

Comment: @Demian. Maybe he's running select * from internet ?

Comment: @Demian its cuz each query makes a robot do some movement...so its just 8 queries per sec

Comment: you know... you submit a form and somewhere a robot does the moon walk.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you let this job to mysql server. It has a built in queue system.
You can tweak it if it doesn't performe as well as you like

Comment: can u guide me a bit on how to use mysql queuing system